# Parser Combinators (ReadP) - return entire list if it fails, otherwise return only the passing one

Tags: haskell

I have a string, for example "MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP". I know that this string may have ABC in it and may have XYZ in it, but it is not required to have either. Additionally, the XYZ may be swapped for DEF (e.g. "MMMMABCNNNDEFPPPPP") and the behavior should remain the same.

I would like to parse the string and return the sequences between them, as well as which one of XYZ or DEF was present. Example:

```
data Divider1 = Abc
data Divider2 = Xyz | Def

--"MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP" should return ("MMMM", Just Abc, "NNN", Just Xyz, "PPPPP")
--"MMMMABCNNNDEFPPPPP" should return ("MMMM", Just Abc, "NNN", Just Def, "PPPPP")
```

Note that if ABC is not present, I would like to return everything before the divider2 and if XYZ and DEF are both not present, I would like to return everything after divider 1.

Example:

```
--"MMMMNNNXYZPPPPP" should return ("MMMM", Nothing, "NNN", Just Xyz, "PPPPP")
--"MMMMABCNNNPPPPP" should return ("MMMM", Just Abc, "NNN", Nothing, "PPPPP")
```

If neither ABC nor XYZ is present then I don't care if it returns nothing, or if it returns the entire string.

Currently my code is

```
parseEverything = many $ satisfy someGeneralCondition--check if all characters are valid

parseAbc = (\str -> Abc) <$> string "ABC"
parseXyz = (\str -> Xyz) <$> string "XYZ"
parseDef = (\str -> Def) <$> string "DEF"

parseFull = do
    beforeAbc <- gather parseEverything
    parseAbc <- (Just <$> parseAbc) <++ return Nothing
    beforeDivider2 <- gather parseEverything
    parseDivider2 <- (Just <$> parseXyz) <++ (Just <$> parseDef) <++ (Just <$> Nothing)
    everythingElse <- look
    return (beforeAbc, parseAbc, beforeDivider2, parseDivider2, everythingElse)
```

But when I run this on the example string "MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP", I get mostly failed results with just one result that I want. The problem is that I need to return everything in `beforeAbc` if `parseAbc` fails, but if `parseAbc` passes then I just need to return that. And the same thing with `parseXyz` and `parseDef`. I don't think that `<++` is the correct operator to do this. I also tried a variant of this code using `option`, but it gave the same result. Is there a simple solution that I am missing, and/or should I set up the parsers in a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: does this have anything to do with chainl or chainr or manyTill?

Comment: I don't know readp well enough to answer this question, but you may be happy to learn that instead of `(\x -> y) <$> z`, you can simply write `y <$ z`

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Is y the same thing as (\x -> y) internally? I thought their types are different.

Comment: No, the difference is that `<$` expects a value, where `<$>` expects a function.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin sorry I accidentally changed the names in the post, they are actually capitalized

Comment: In  the example where you parse `"MMMMNNNXYZPPPPP"`, how does the parser determine that `"MMMM"` and `"NNN"` should be split when there's no divider between them?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr hmm, they shouldn't be split. That's probably part of the problem - it is hard to standardize the type of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated:* See note on applicative parsers below.

Here's what's going wrong with your current approach. As you undoubtedly know, the parsers in `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` generate all possible valid parses of all possible prefixes of the string.  If you write a parser:

```
letterAndOther = do
  letters <- many (satisfy isLetter)
  others <- many get
  return (letters, others)
```

which grabs an initial string of letters followed by the "rest" of the string and run it on a simple test string, you'll usually get way more than you bargained for:

```
> readP_to_S letterAndOther "abc"
[(("",""),"abc"),(("","a"),"bc"),(("a",""),"bc"),(("","ab"),"c"),
(("a","b"),"c"),(("ab",""),"c"),(("","abc"),""),(("a","bc"),""),
(("ab","c"),""),(("abc",""),"")]
```

In other words, in a do-block, each monadic action will typically generate a tree of possible parses.  In your current code, the very first line of the do-block:

```
beforeAbc <- gather parseEverything
```

introduces a whole tree of parse branches, one branch for each possible initial prefix.  These branches only get pruned if a later line of the do-block introduces a parse that fails.  But, every line of your do-block represents a parser that always succeeds.  For example, this always succeeds:

```
parseAbc <- (Just <$> parseAbc) <++ return Nothing
```

because even if the first divider isn't found, the right-hand side parser `return Nothing` will always succeed.

I would suggest the following approach. First, as we discovered in the comments, the first thing you want to do is figure out what your parser should return.  Instead of trying to shoehorn the result into a weird tuple, it's a good idea to leverage Haskell's best feature, it's algebraic data types.  Define a return type for your parse:

```
data Result
  = TwoDividers   String Divider1 String Divider2 String
  | FirstDivider  String Divider1 String
  | SecondDivider String Divider2 String
  | NoDividers    String
```

This is unambiguous and covers all possibilities.  Admittedly, including `Divider1` in the first two constructors is redundant, since there's only one possible `Divider1`, but programs are for humans to read, too, and keeping `Divider1` explicit improves readability.

Now, let's define parsers for the first and second dividers:

```
divider1 = Abc <$ string "ABC"
divider2 = (Def <$ string "DEF") +++ (Xyz <$ string "XYZ")
```

Note that I've chosen to define a single `divider2` instead of separate parsers for `Def` and `Xyz`. Since, in your grammar, it's always the case that "DEF" can appear anywhere "XYZ" can and vice versa, it makes sense to combine them into one parser.

We'll also want a parser for arbitrary strings (basically your `parseEverything`):

```
anything = many $ satisfy isLetter -- valid characters
```

Now, let's write a parser for the full string.  A key insight here is that we have four alternatives (i.e., the four constructors for our `Result` type).  It's true that they share some structure, but a first crack at a parser can just treat them as independent alternatives.  We'll use the `<++` operator to choose the best match:

```
result =
      (TwoDividers <$> anything <*> divider1 <*> anything <*> divider2 <*> anything)
  <++ (FirstDivider <$> anything <*> divider1 <*> anything)
  <++ (SecondDivider <$> anything <*> divider2 <*> anything)
  <++ (NoDividers <$> anything)
```

A quick test of this will show we've forgotten something:

```
> readP_to_S result "MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP"
[(TwoDividers "MMMM" Abc "NNN" Xyz "","PPPPP"),...]
```

By default, the parser combinators will try every possible prefix of the input string, leaving more for later parsers.  So, we should wrap this up in a final parser function that checks for the end-of-string:

```
parseResult = readP_to_S (result <* eof)
```

and with the tests:

```
main = mapM_ (print . parseResult)
  [ "MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP"
  , "MMMMABCNNNDEFPPPPP"
  , "MMMMNNNXYZPPPPP"
  , "MMMMABCNNNPPPPP"
  ]
```

we get the expected unique parsed output:

```
[(TwoDividers "MMMM" Abc "NNN" Xyz "PPPPP","")]
[(TwoDividers "MMMM" Abc "NNN" Def "PPPPP","")]
[(SecondDivider "MMMMNNN" Xyz "PPPPP","")]
[(FirstDivider "MMMM" Abc "NNNPPPPP","")]
```

**Note on Applicative Parsers.**  I've used applicative syntax here, rather than the monad syntax. The difference isn't purely syntactical -- you can always write an applicative expression in monadic form, but there are monadic operations that can't be expressed applicatively, so the monadic syntax is strictly more powerful.  However, when an expression can be written both ways, often the applicative syntax is more succinct and easier to write and understand, at least once you get used to it.

In a nutshell, the expression `p <*> x <*> y <*> z` creates a new parser that applies the parsers `p`, `x`, `y`, and `z` in order, and then applies the result from parser `p` (which needs to be a function `f`) to the results from the rest of the parsers (which must be appropriate arguments for `f`).  In many cases, the function `f` is a known function and doesn't need to be returned by a parser, so a common variant is to write `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`.  This applies the parsers `x`, `y`, and `z` in order, and then applies `f` (given directly instead of returned by a parser) to the results from those parsers.  For example, the expression:

```
FirstDivider <$> anything <*> divider1 <*> anything
```

runs three parsers in order to get `anything`, followed by a `divider1`, followed by `anything`, and then applies the function/contructor `FirstDivider` to the three arguments resulting from those parsers.

The operators `<*` and `*>` can be thought of as variants of `<*>`.  The expression `p <*> x` first parses `p`, then parses `x`, then applies the result of the former to the latter.  The expression `p <* x` first parses `p`, then parses `x`, but instead of applying the former to the latter, it returns the value the arrow is pointing to (i.e., whatever `p` produced) and throws away the other value.  Similarly `p *> x` parses `p` then parses `x`, then returns whatever `x` produced.  In particular:

```
someParser <* eof
```

first runs `someParser`, then parses (i.e., checks for) EOF, then returns whatever `someParser` produced.

This syntax can really shine when parsing more traditional languages into an abstract syntax tree.  If you want to parse statements like:

```
let x = 1 + 5
```

into a `Statement` type like:

```
data Statement = ... | Let Var Expr | ...
```

you can write a Parsec parser that looks like:

```
statement = ...
  <|> Let <$ string "let" <*> var <* symbol "=" <*> expr
  ...
```

The monadic equivalent in do-notation looks like this:

```
do string "let"
   v <- var
   symbol "="
   e <- expr
   return $ Let v e
```

which is fine, I suppose, but kind of obscures the simple structure of the parse.  The applicative version is basically just the list of tokens to parse, with a little bit of syntactic sugar sprinkled in.

Anyway, here's the full program:

```
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

data Divider1 = Abc deriving (Show)
data Divider2 = Xyz | Def deriving (Show)

data Result
  = TwoDividers   String Divider1 String Divider2 String
  | FirstDivider  String Divider1 String
  | SecondDivider String Divider2 String
  | NoDividers    String
  deriving (Show)

anything :: ReadP String
anything = many $ satisfy isLetter  -- valid characters

divider1 :: ReadP Divider1
divider1 = Abc <$ string "ABC"

divider2 :: ReadP Divider2
divider2 = (Def <$ string "DEF") +++ (Xyz <$ string "XYZ")

result :: ReadP Result
result =
      (TwoDividers <$> anything <*> divider1 <*> anything <*> divider2 <*> anything)
  <++ (FirstDivider <$> anything <*> divider1 <*> anything)
  <++ (SecondDivider <$> anything <*> divider2 <*> anything)
  <++ (NoDividers <$> anything)

parseResult :: String -> [(Result, String)]
parseResult = readP_to_S (result <* eof)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (print . parseResult)
  [ "MMMMABCNNNXYZPPPPP"
  , "MMMMABCNNNDEFPPPPP"
  , "MMMMNNNXYZPPPPP"
  , "MMMMABCNNNPPPPP"
  ]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this very well-explained response! What is the `<*` operator (which you used in `parseResult`)? Do you have any tips for understanding applicative parsers? I find it much easier to just deal with them as functors and monads.

Comment: I added a note about applicative parsers.  Once you get used to them, they're often easier to write (and read/understand) than their equivalent monadic forms.

Comment: Why include the divider in the result when you can just use `<*` to get rid of it?

Comment: I did mention in the answer: "Admittedly, including Divider1 in the first two constructors is redundant, since there's only one possible Divider1, but programs are for humans to read, too, and keeping Divider1 explicit improves readability."  Obviously, there's room for disagreement on this point.